# Get youtube video title while video downloading

Tags: bash, youtube

In my bash script I consistently download video:

```
youtube-dl -f mp4 -o '%(id)s.%(ext)s' --no-warnings $URL
```

and then getting video title:

```
TITLE=$(youtube-dl --skip-download --get-title --no-warnings $URL | sed 2d)
```

Both of these commands take some time: the former takes 1-10 min (depending on video duration), and the latter takes 10-20 seconds.

Is there any way to get video title in background while downloading video?

PS. I can't send to background first command (download video) because after I work with video file: get file size and duration for item meta in rss feed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you could run the second command in background, thus making two requests to YouTube, better would be to **do it with a single call** to `youtube-dl`, using the [`--print-json`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#verbosity--simulation-options) option, combined with a [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) filter:

```
title=$(youtube-dl -f mp4 -o '%(id)s.%(ext)s' --print-json --no-warnings "$url" | jq -r .title)
```

Video will be downloaded in background, and all video details will be printed right away. You can then filter the fields of interest with `jq` as above, or **store them for later** use:

```
youtube-dl -f mp4 -o '%(id)s.%(ext)s' --print-json --no-warnings "$url" >metadata
title=$(jq -r ".title" metadata)
duration=$(jq -r ".duration" metadata)
view_count=$(jq -r ".view_count" metadata)
```

---

In case you wish to have **progress output while downloading** and store metadata to a JSON file, you'll have to use the [`--write-info-json`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#filesystem-options) option instead. The data will be stored in the file named as your video file, but with extension `.info.json`. For example:

```
youtube-dl -f mp4 -o 'video.%(ext)s' --write-info-json "$url"
title=$(jq -r ".title" "video.info.json")
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Can I make youtube-dl output to STDOUT download progress?

Comment: In that case you might want to use the `--write-info-json` option instead. See my update.